# Tag layout broken when asking question

Tags: bug, design

When asking a question and entering the tags, it can happen that the content appears cropped.

[image: Screenshot: Tag layout broken]

This is Windows 7 SP1, Firefox 36.0, 100% zoom and AdBlock disabled. 1280x1024 screen size, maximized window. Similar in IE 11.0.9600.17633.